# How to forward message responses with ruby Lita?

Tags: ruby, hipchat, lita

I am working with a chatbot operating on the [lita ruby gem](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lita/Lita) using lita-hipchat.  After a response is made to lita using hipchat, lita will be able to return messages to the user who created the response through [the reply method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lita/Lita/Message#reply-instance_method). I would like to change this pattern and be able to send a hipchat to a secondary user, essentially being able to cc or forward that same response to more than one user. Is this possible using only the Lita gem?

I am aware that sending messages through http or the hipchat gem is another option for sending messages to secondary users, but I would prefer to do this through lita.

Comment: how do you determine who the 2ndary user even is?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but it looks like you should just be able to mention whoever you want in your response. So my prefix your response with the mention name `@someonelse Here is my response`. Similar to what they are doing in the source [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lita/Lita%2FRobot:send_messages_with_mention)

Comment: @lacostenycoder the secondary user can be located using account details such as emails attached to users, the lita redis database and the Lita::User object https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lita/Lita/User finding this will provide all the details that are needed to match those found in the response objects used to send replys

Comment: @AntarrByrd Thats a good sugestion if these messages were being sent to a room available to be viewed by multiple users.  However I am looking for a method of sending a private message to two distinct users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Robot#send_messages](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lita/Lita%2FRobot:send_messages). For example:

```
def my_handler_route(response)
  user2 = Lita::User.find_by_id("user2")
  target = Lita::Source(user: user2)
  robot.send_message(target, "This message will go to User2!")
end
```

This is essentially what `Response#reply` is doing—but with the convenience of automatically targeting the original source.

Comment: That worked! I prefer using Lita::User.find_by_name instead of Lita::User.find_by_id, but both work: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/lita/Lita/User#find_by_name-class_method